# How to stop running thread of Fragment safely on android?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-fragments

I want to know how to stop running thread and asyncTask of fragment safely on android.

here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    public Fragment mFragment;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button btn_next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_next);
        btn_next.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ((FragmentOne)mFragment).infoThread.interrupt();
            }
        });

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String start_fragment = intent.getStringExtra("start_fragment"); 

        onShowFragment(start_fragment);
    }

    public void onShowFragment(String select_fragment) {

        Fragment fr = null;

        switch (select_fragment) {
        case "fragment1":
            fr = new FragmentOne();
            break;
        case "gragment2":
            fr = new FragmentTwo();
            break;
        }

        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction(); 
        ft.replace(R.id.fragment_place, fr); 
        ft.commit(); 
    }
  }

  public class FragmentOne extends Fragment {

    public Thread infoThread;
    public View view_one;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        view_one = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);

        onGetInfo();
        return view_one;
    }

    public void onGetInfo() {

        infoThread= new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                String response_info = HTTPUtils.HTTPPost(Global.USER_URL, 
                        "name", "abc", 
                        "password", "1234");
                processGetInfo(response_info);
            }
        });
        infoThread.start();
    } 

  }
```

in here, when click **btn_next button**, **FATAL EXCEPTION** ERROR occur.
please help me.

Comment: Sorry, but I should use only Thread, not AsyncTask.

Answer (score 0):

try to use:

```
infoThread.stop()
```

instead of:

```
infoThread.interrupt();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are never initialising `mFragment` with a value.

Add `mFragment = fr;` to `onShowFragment`

But, you're going to have a whole load of different issues if you carry on down this path. You should consider a more robust framework than performing http requests in threads spawned from a Fragment's onCreateView method.